# Why in ASP.NET MVC 3 the default route is not working for a controller called "ContentController"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a brand new asp.net mvc 3 project. I did not modify the routes in any way. I have a controller called `PageController` and another controller call `ContentController`.

When I browse to domain.com/Page then the Index action on the Page controller gets executed as expected and displays the Index view.

When I browse to domain.com/Content I get a 404 error. If I browse to domain.com/Content/Index then it works fine.

How do I troubleshoot this single route?

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        ); 
    }
```

I tried adding an additional route:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        ); 
        routes.MapRoute(
             "Content", // Route name
             "Content/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Content", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
         );

    }
```

But the additional route did not change the application's behavior.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Just to clarify, can you add the code for the `ContentController`

Comment: @MatthewAbbott - It's all generated through scaffolding. I was able to resolve the issue by implementing Nathan's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

its because there is a physical folder called content.  having a controller with the same name as a physical folder will probably have some adverse affects on your website.

Comment: Huh... this makes sense. I'll try renaming the controller.

Comment: Just ran into this after banging my head against the wall for abit, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thank god i searched for "ContentController"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your route definitions:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Comment: won't he then have to set up routes or ignore routes for his actual content files?

Comment: I betcha this would work. But, I think the root problem is outlined by @nathangonzalez.